# Laptop screen flashing vertical lines

Tags: laptop, display, acer-aspire

my laptop sometimes flash vertical lines on the screen. It happens very random. When I restart the laptop it stops.

I bought it 9 months ago. It still has guarantee but they already kept my laptop over a month "fixing the problem" but it still the same. Can anybody help me ?

It's an Acer aspire 3 A315-58
Windows 11
i3 1115g4
8gb ram
255gb m2

This is a picture of the exact moment when the screen flashes those lines
[image: This is a picture of the exact moment when the screen flashes those lines]

Comment: Looks like either a screen or ribbon cable fail. Either way, if the supplier can't fix it [should be a ten minute job] then they are obliged to exchange it.

Answer (score 1):

First step should be to isolate the problem, by taking a screenshot when this
is happening *via Windows* (not with your camera).
You may use the PrtSc key that copies the image to the clipboard.

If the image shows the lines, then the problem is with the display
adapter, so ensure you have the best driver (downloaded from the
manufacturer).
If this doesn't help, the display adapter is defective.

If the image doesn't show the lines, then the problem is with the
screen, and the only solution is to replace it (or check the cables).